# explorer.exe starts every five minutes a new window (win 10)

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

my problem is pretty simple, but i could not find a solution.

Problem:
explorer.exe starts every five minutes (more or less) and opens the same folder (my documents folder on c:), over and over again. My OS: Win 10

Process Hacker shows this: 
Command line: C:\Windows\explorer.exe /factory,{75dff2b7-6936-4c06-a8bb-676a7b00b24b} -Embedding
Parent: svchost.exe (968)

Also many instances of RuntimeBroker.exe are running
Command line: C:\Windows\System32\RuntimeBroker.exe -Embedding
Parent: svchost.exe (968)

Process Hacker showed me these processes within svchost.exe (968):
runtimebroker.exe (multiple),
localbridge.exe (killed shortly after),
backgroundtaskhost.exe,
ApplicationFrameHost.exe,
SettingSyncHost.exe,
dllhost.exe (multiple),
unsecapp.exe,
WmiPrvSE.exe,
SkypeApp.exe (suspended),
SkypeBackgroundHost.exe (suspended),
ShellExperienceHost.exe (suspended),
SearchUI.exe (suspended),
explorer.exe (multiple and main problem).

I used the common antivirus, maleware, rootkit and registry scanners, but found nothing to solve the problem. sfc / scannow said that everything is fine.

My question is: what exactly is starting explorer.exe over and over again (which process/program?) and how can i stop it and solve the problem?

Every help is appreciated.

Comment: svchost.exe is used, which means that whatever it is doing, it is a service. you could stop all services until the problem stops. I would start with Windows Update, but Windows Search is another possibility.

Comment: In addition to doing updates, open an Admin Command Prompt and run (1) dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth and then (2) SFC /SCANNOW  .  Restart when done. If you think Search is doing something, then check the Search Location properties and rebuild the index if you change anything.

Comment: While the Explorer window is open open Task Scheduler and look for running tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, it was indeed a Windows service: Task Scheduler

I started the scheduler and looked into the different tasks/triggers that were in it. I found two recently started ones, and one had a trigger to start every six minutes a file (a file which was deleted by my av program). So it is most likely a relic from a maleware/trojan i had. After deleting the two entries in the task scheduler everything is now back to normal.

For further info:
Name: PrintPool Service; Trigger: Every 6 minutes; Starts: explorer.exe c:\users\public\explorer.js
Name: SoundIndex_d936819b; Starts: wmic process call create C:\Users\Public\prnjobs.data:d936819b